# ¿Cómo evitar la doble ejecución de submit en JQuery o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de evitar que al dar N clicks a un botón se ejecute N veces la operación. Por ejemplo: si doy clic dos veces a un botón, se inserta dos veces a la base de datos. Lo que intenté hacer es que cuando de el primer click se deshabilite el botón, y sí lo deshabilita pero aunque esté deshabilitado ejecuta el submit. Les dejo el código que tengo:

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnAddState" name="btnAddState" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1" onclick="myFunction()">Guardar</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
      if ($('#name').val() !== undefined && $('#name').val().trim() == '') {
            alert('Ingresá un Nombre');
            return;
      }
      $('#btnAddState').addClass("disabled");
}
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Hola, intenta deshabilitarlo por atributo, no como clase para que deje de aceptar clicks.

Comment: Hola, así como comentas sí me lo deshabilita pero no me ejecuta ninguna acción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto como yo lo haría con jquery, capturaría el evento click del botón y ahí valido el formulario, si todo ok, desabilito el botón y disparo el submit. Espero te sirva.

```js
$('#btnAddState').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Para evitar se dispare el submit

  // Aplicas tus validaciones
  if ($('#name').val() !== undefined && $('#name').val().trim() == '') {
      alert('Ingresá un Nombre');
      return;
  }

  $(this).prop('disabled', true); // Desactivas el botón
  $(this).submit(); // Disparas el submit una vez desactivado el botón
});


// Esto solo para mostrar que el submit no se envía mas de una vez
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  console.log('send'); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <button type="submit" id="btnAddState" name="btnAddState" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-5 mx-1">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

yo hago uso de esta función para resolver el problema que tu indicas

```
enviando = false; //Obligaremos a entrar el if en el primer submit

function checkSubmit() {
  if (!enviando) {
   enviando= true;
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}
```